# Get base class properties in C# source generation - IIncrementalGenerator

Tags: c#, csharp-source-generator

I have following Execute method in my source generator. I can get all the properties (x.Item1.Members.AsEnumerable()...) of my class. But I can't manage to get the properties of the base class too. How can I list all properties of the base class?

```
    private static void Execute(Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray<(ClassDeclarationSyntax, AttributeData)> classes, SourceProductionContext context)
    {
        foreach (var (x, i) in classes.Select((x, i) => (x, i)))
        {
            TypedConstant aggregateParam = x.Item2.ConstructorArguments[0];
            if (aggregateParam.Kind == TypedConstantKind.Primitive &&
                aggregateParam.Value is string fullyQualifiedAggregateName)
            {
                var aggregateName = "Aggregate";

                var props = x.Item1.Members.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration));

                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                context.AddSource(
                    $"generated_{aggregateName}_{i}.g.cs",
                    sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

```
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            IncrementalValuesProvider<(ClassDeclarationSyntax, AttributeData)> classDeclarations = context.SyntaxProvider
                .ForAttributeWithMetadataName(
                    EventApplyAttribute,
                    predicate: static (node, _) => node is ClassDeclarationSyntax,
                    transform: static (ctx, ct) => GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(ctx, ct))
                .Where(m => m.Item1 is not null && m.Item2 is not null);

            IncrementalValueProvider<(Compilation, ImmutableArray<(ClassDeclarationSyntax, AttributeData)>)> compilationAndClasses
                = context.CompilationProvider.Combine(classDeclarations.Collect());

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(compilationAndClasses,
                static (spc, source) => Execute(source.Item1, source.Item2, spc));
        }

        private static (ClassDeclarationSyntax, AttributeData) GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(GeneratorAttributeSyntaxContext context, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            if (context.TargetNode is not ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
            {
                return (null, null);
            }

            AttributeData? attribute = context.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeClass?.Name == "EventApplyAttribute");

            return (classDeclaration, attribute);
        }
```

Comment: You **MUST NOT** include Compilation in the incremental pipeline.

Comment: @Youssef13 when you use `RegisterImplementationSourceOutput` in the incremental pipeline, it literally gives you the `Compilation` in the callback, which is *presumably* what Dani is talking about here, since that's also the API that gives you `ImmutableArray<TSource>` for your `TSource` (in this case `ClassDeclarationSyntax`); it is literally impossible to avoid the `Compilation`

Comment: There are cases where it's hard/impossible to avoid, but those are considered cases not suitable for source generators. But generally speaking, compilation should **never** be included in the pipeline. You get it in the transform, but you shouldn't return it back, instead, the information needed should be extracted into a value-equatable model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you want the semantic model for this - not the syntax model. And you don't need to wait for `Execute` for that - when using incremental generators, presumably you're using `CreateSyntaxProvider`, where you provide a *pre-filter* on the syntax model, and a *transform* that is more flexible. In that transform, you can access the semantic model. This is advantageous for performance, as it allows any processing in your transform step to be cached as long as the relevant syntax tree is not invalidated.

During transform, you can get the semantic model via `ctx.SemanticModel` - you *probably* want `ctx.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(...)` on the `ClassDeclarationSyntax`. Since this is declaring a type, the symbol it gives you should be an `ITypeSymbol` and very likely a `INamedTypeSymbol`. This means you have now full access to the type data, including `.BaseType`.

But: at either transform or execute, you can get the semantic model

You can also get the semantic model at `Execute` via `state.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(...)` passing in the syntax-tree for a relevant syntax-node, but: if you're doing that, you're probably repeating a lot of work, adversely impacting IDE performance.

Comment: To add to that, the `transform` step should produce a value-equatable custom model that must not include compilation or symbols. Instead, it should extract what it needs from compilation/symbols.

Comment: @Youssef13 out of curiosity, any citation on that?

Comment: Well, that info is quite hidden with chats with Roslyn team over the Discord channel. But there is a hint on that at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md#authoring-a-cache-friendly-generator.
btw, that is why it's difficult to write incremental generators or convert existing non-incremental to incremental ones. You can also see an example GH issue for a generator that includes compilation in the pipeline https://github.com/k94ll13nn3/AutoConstructor/issues/82.